# Is there any way to pause a for loop until a variable is true

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to pause a for loop until a variable is true? For example, if I had this code,

```
var flag = false; 
for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

and `i` was equal to 7, could I pause the loop until `flag = true`?

Thanks!

Comment: No... sounds like you're trying to solve a problem the wrong way. Why do you want to pause the loop?

Comment: You could look into promises that get resolved and then within the loop start awaiting that promise when i==7: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises

Comment: @tymeJV I'm making a Simon Game and I don't want my loop to continue until the user clicks on some of the buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript is a single-thread event-based model: if you could pause the execution you couldn't evaluate your flag during that time.

Also, if the value of the flag depends on an user event, you want to wait for the event to fire and not for the variable to change.

If, like in your example, you know beforehand when you want to pause the loop, you should split it:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 7; i++){
    console.log(i);
}

document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  for(var i = 8; i < 15; i++){
      console.log(i);
  }
}
```

If you don't know it (because it is decided inside the `for` loop) you just need to ensure that the next time the loop starts in the point it stopped (e.g., by reusing the `i` variable).

```
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  if (Math.random() < 0.2) { break; }
}

document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  for (i++; i < 15; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

If the code inside the loop is long you can wrap it inside a function (thanks @*tom*):

```
function logIndex() {
  //some code
  console.log(i);
}
```

Actually, you can isolate all the logic to manage the loop and the user event in a single function that, recursively, creates a handler for the user event to call itself. It has also the advantage that you can stop the loop as many times as needed.

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");

function logIndexes(index) {
  for (index; index < 15; index++) {
    console.log(index);
    if (Math.random() <= 0.2) {
      return button.onclick = function() {
        logIndexes(index + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  button.onclick = null;
}

logIndexes(0);
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Ok... I'll try that.

Comment: Is there a way to re-enter the loop without making a new for loop with the same variable?

Comment: @stephenpassero No there isn't.

Comment: @stephenpassero If the body of the for-loop is long, you can avoid duplication by moving the body to a new function and then calling that function from both loops. You can pass `i` to the function so it knows which iteration is in progress.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an interval an a timeout for simulating a loop and for changing the `flag`.

```js
function count(start, end, inc) {
    var i = start;
    return function () {
        if (i === 8 && ! flag) {
            return;        
        }
        console.log(i);
        i += inc;        
        if (i >= end) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }
}


var flag = false,
    interval = setInterval(count(0, 10, 1), 500);

setTimeout(function () {
    flag = true;
}, 10000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: OP said until the variable is true how 10000 ms is until?. To be honest he should use an Observable pattern. Get the loop running till 7th iteration and observe for an event that sets the flag to true and then continue the iteration from 8th onwards

Answer (score 0):

No. A loop will execute until a condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var flag = false; 
for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){ 
    If ((i > 6) && (! flag)){
        i = 6;
    } else {
         console.log(i); 
    }
}
```

This will made an infinite loop, but I think you know how & where flag will be true, may be the syntax is not true, but I give you the  idea of how to pause a loop...

Answer (score 0):

ES6 has something called generators which may be helpful to you. It's not a for loop but could "pause" your script.
Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

```js
function* idMaker() {
  let index = 0;
  while (index < 15) {
    yield index++;
  }
}

var gen = idMaker();

//console.log(gen.next().value);
//console.log(gen.next().value);

for (i of gen) {
  if (gen.next().done) {
    console.log('all done');
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```