# stop a running function on button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

my html file

```
<script>
    let socket = io();
    socket.on('update-value', function (value) { // When a 'update-value' event is received, execute the following code.
            console.log('received new value', value);

          //  $('#myname').html(value);
          $('#div1').prepend(value);

        });
        socket.on('checking-value', function (value) { // When a 'update-value' event is received, execute the following code.
            console.log('received new value', value);

            $('#name').prepend(value);

      
        });

        function searchStart() {
            socket.emit('searchStart')
            const button = document.querySelector('#startbtn')
            button.disabled = true
        }

        function searchStop() {
            socket.emit('searchStop', 1)
            const button = document.querySelector('#stopbtn')
            button.disabled = true
        }
    </script>
```

server side js file

```
socket.on("searchStart", () => {

  runScript()
})

socket.on("searchStop", () => {

  // ??????????
})
```

the runScript function has a ton of for loops constantly fetching data and displaying em on the html page,

what i want is to make a stop button that stops all the ongoing for loops and data fetching "runScript function" from running on the server side untill i hit the start button again

Comment: What does the `runScript` function look like? Well, maybe if you put some boolean (ex. `isSearchEnabled`) outside these 2 `socket.on(` -calls that both of them have access to it and simply set it to true or false whenever you want, then before fetching this data just check if it's true or false? :)

Comment: RxJS? AbortController? A simple flag?

Comment: Does this answers you question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701488/is-there-any-way-to-pause-a-for-loop-until-a-variable-is-true